# How to add new line in bootstrap modal box

Tags: jquery

I wrote an code to display json data in bootstrap table..Here how can add a new line in modal-box.. and is it possible to add title along with data in modal-box..

**For example :**

**Reg.NO:** 1122340

**Student Name:** john

**Department:** CSE

**Yop:** 2016

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
       <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       
    <script>
    var studentDetails=[
    {
    "regno":"1122340",
    "name":"John",
    "dept":"CSE",
    "yop": "2016",
    "action":"Show"
    },
    {
    "regno":"1122341",
    "name":"Brisen",
    "dept": "MECH",
    "yop":"2015",
    "action":"Show"
    },
    {
    "regno":"1122342",
    "name":"Moksha",
    "dept": "EEE",
    "yop":"2016",
    "action":"Show"
    },
    {
    "regno":"1122343",
    "name":"Mano",
    "dept": "IT",
    "yop":"2013",
    "action":"Show"
    },
    {
    "regno":"1122344",
    "name":"Jothish",
    "dept": "AERO",
    "yop":"2012",
    "action":"Show"
    }
    ];
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    
    for(var i=0;i<studentDetails.length;i++)
    {
      var tab='<tr><td>'+ studentDetails[i].regno +"\n"+'</td><td>'+ studentDetails[i].name +"\n"+'</td><td>'+
       studentDetails[i].dept +"\n"+'</td><td>'+ studentDetails[i].yop +"\n"+'</td><td><button class="show" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-html="true">'+
        studentDetails[i].action +'</button></td></tr>';
        $('#student').append(tab)
    };
    $(".show").click(function(){
    $(".modal-body").html('');
    res=$(this).closest('tr').clone().find('button').remove().end().text();
    $(".modal-body").append(res);
    });
    }); 
    </script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <div class="container">
          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Student Details</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="student">
         <tr>
         <th>Register No</th>
         <th>Student Name</th>
         <th>Department</th>
         <th>Year Of Passed Out</th>
         <th>Action</th>
         </tr>
        </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try this one `for (var i = 0; i < studentDetails.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr class=""/>');
    tr.append('<td>' + studentDetails[i].regno + "\n" + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + studentDetails[i].name + "\n" + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + studentDetails[i].dept + "\n" + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + studentDetails[i].yop + "\n" + '</td>');
    tr.append('<td><button class="show" data-toggle="modal"  data-target="#myModal" data-html="true">' +
      studentDetails[i].action + '</button></td>');
    $('#student tbody').append(tr)
  };`

Comment: @Shivkumar no changes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (imho) could be to do something like this:

```
res=$(this).closest('tr').clone().find('button').remove().end().text();
reso=res.split("\n");

reso='Reg.NO:'+reso[0]+'<br>Student Name:'+reso[1]+'<br>Department:'+reso[2]+'<br>Yop:'+reso[3];
$(".modal-body").append(reso);
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ar63c0qL/